# Facebook App Not Setup - Development Mode

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I know there are quite a few questions already asked in regards to this, but I couldn't find one that answers my current question exactly.

I am currently working on an app that is not ready to be set to live. I am trying to distribute it to people to test, and allow them to test the Facebook Social functionality.

I was trying to distribute it with the main Facebook app being in Development mode initially, but this would not allow anybody except for Administrator/Developer accounts to log in. Then I created a test app, leaving the main app in development mode and again, the users could not log in. I just now had the idea to put the main app into "Live" mode, and only distribute a version of the game with the test app's AppID, and this seems to be working fine now.

My question is, is this the way that testing has to be done? Does the main app NEED to be set to live for any test apps to work at all? Or is there a way to allow test apps to log in without setting the main app to live?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your users under Roles => Roles (Testers)? (NOT Roles => Test Users). This would allow your app to stay private, but allow people to test on it.